# Extract items delimited with square brackets using python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split out words/phrases delimited by square brackets using a python regular expression. I want to split the output. Conditions are that section of text beginning and ending with square brackets will be split into a different element.

This is what I have so far but it doesn't work properly:

```
import re
t="word1 word2 3456 [abc def] [ghi jkl] [1234] [-abcd] word 2345"
re.split("(\[)(.*)(\])+",t)
```

Output:

```
['word1 word2 3456 ',
'[',
'abc def] [ghi jkl] [1234] [-abcd',
']',
' word [xyz 2345']
```

I want the output to be something like:

```
['word1 word2 3456 ',
 '[abc def]',
 ' ',
 '[ghi jkl]',
 ' ',
 '[1234]',
 ' ',
 '[-abcd]',
 ' word [xyz 2345']
```

Note only the items with both an opening and closing square bracket are split out.

I've also tried this:

```
re.split("(\[.*\])+",t)
```

but that only splits by the first and last square bracket

```
['word1 word2 3456 ', '[abc def] [ghi jkl] [1234] [-abcd]', ' word [xyz 2345']
```

Comment: You probably want `re.findall` or `re.finditer`, not `re.split`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.+?` instead of `.*`:

```
>>> re.split("(\[.+?\])", t)
['word1 word2 3456 ', '[abc def]', ' ', '[ghi jkl]', ' ', '[1234]', ' ', '[-abcd]', ' word 2345']
```

Comment: that's right! I forgot that `re.split` keeps splitters that are in capturing groups. Good answer +1

Comment: Very clever dav, I didn't know this +1

Comment: Didn't know that with splitters! plus also :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex to split your strings:

```
\s(?=\[)|(?<=\])\s
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/dH6xL4/1)**

[image]

But since it splits those spaces it will consume them and your generated output will be:

```
word1 word2 3456
[abc def]
[ghi jkl]
[1234]
[-abcd] word 2345
```

So, as a workaround you can use above regex to replace the matches with a custom token like `||| |||` to generate something like:

```
word1 word2 3456||| |||[abc def]||| |||[ghi jkl]||| |||[1234]||| |||[-abcd]||| |||word 2345
```

Then you can use the split method on your custom token `|||` and it will keep the spaces too as:

```
'word1 word2 3456'
' '
'[abc def]'
' '
'[ghi jkl]'
' '
'[1234]'
' '
'[-abcd]'
' '
'word '
```

Comment: this won't be quite right since it will remove the spaces, but it's about as close as you can get with `re.split`

Comment: @AdamSmith yes your are right. Btw, I've updated the answer with a little workaround to get OP output... it's just to suggest an idea

Comment: Seems what he wants, why not doing a [zero-width split](http://regex101.com/r/dH6xL4/4)? `(?<=])|(?=\[)` however plus :)

Comment: @Jonny5 lol! I didn't think about it. Can I update my answer with it?

Comment: Ooooh! [And now I see](http://ideone.com/4Ce0nM), that Python re obviously does not support zero-width split (does it with any flags?). [The manual says](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#contents-of-module-re): `Note that split will never split a string on an empty pattern match...` and there's also [a discussion](http://bugs.python.org/issue3262). So better cut out my idea of the answer :p

Comment: @Jonny5 ok, good to know it was a very good idea, it's a pitty that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
re.findall(r"[^\]\[]*|\[[^\]\[]*?\]", t)
```

This will return

```
['word1 word2 3456 ', '', 'abc def', '', ' ', '', 'ghi jkl', '', ' ', '', '1234', '', ' ', '', '-abcd', '', ' word 2345', '']
```

To remove the empty strings, do:

```
list(filter(None, re.findall(r"[^\]\[]*|\[[^\]\[]*?\]", t)))
```

which returns

```
['word1 word2 3456 ', 
 'abc def',
 ' ',
 'ghi jkl',
 ' ',
 '1234',
 ' ',
 '-abcd',
 ' word 2345']
```

To explain the regex:

```
re.compile(r"""
    [^\]\[]*     # Zero or more characters that aren't [ or ]
    |            # OR
    \[           # a literal [
    [^\]\[]*?    # Zero or more characters that aren't [ or ]
    \]           # a literal ]""", re.X)
```